# protobuf installed using brew but not found in build process

Tags: makefile, protocol-buffers, homebrew, caffe, matcaffe

**Background**

Yesterday I built [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html) and had no problems with its dependencies.

Today I had problems building the Caffe Matlab wrappers due to protobuf dependencies not being found. So I rebuilt Caffe: `make clean` followed by a `make all`, hoping that would fix the problem.

Now the Caffe build is complaining about the protobuf dependency.

The error output is given at the bottom of this question.

Between the original (successful) build and the failed build, I needed to `pip install protobuf` to allow the Caffe python wrappers to import protobuf, as python complained about not being able to find the protobuf package. That was the only "change" involving protobuf prior to the failed Caffe rebuild.

I have tried reinstalling protobuf using brew, but this did not help.

So essentially the chronology of events relating to protobuf are as follows:

```
1. protobuf installed from source using brew:
     brew install --build-from-source --with-python --fresh -vd protobuf
2. caffe built successfully  
3. caffe python wrappers failed to build -- protobuf not found
4. pip install protobuf
5. caffe python wrappers built successfully
6. caffe matlab wrappers failed to build -- protobuf not found
7. tried to rebuild caffe -- failed -- protobuf not found
8. reinstalled protobuf from source using brew
9. tried again to rebuild caffe -- failed -- protobuf not found
```

Whenever protobuf was not found, `brew list --versions` showed that protobuf (2.6.1) was installed.

**Question**

Can someone please explain why protobuf is not being found when it is clearly installed?

What is particularly confusing is the fact that it was found initially (during the original, successful build) and now it is not being found despite following the same approach.

Here is the error output:

```
$ make clean
$ make all -j8
[... truncated ...]
CXX examples/mnist/convert_mnist_data.cpp
CXX examples/siamese/convert_mnist_siamese_data.cpp
CXX .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc
AR -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a(cudnn_conv_layer.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a(cudnn_pooling_layer.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a(cudnn_relu_layer.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a(cudnn_sigmoid_layer.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a(cudnn_softmax_layer.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a(cudnn_tanh_layer.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a(cudnn.o) has no symbols
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::WriteStringWithSizeToArray(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned char*)", referenced from:
      caffe::Datum::SerializeWithCachedSizesToArray(unsigned char*) const in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::FillerParameter::SerializeWithCachedSizesToArray(unsigned char*) const in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::NetParameter::SerializeWithCachedSizesToArray(unsigned char*) const in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::SolverParameter::SerializeWithCachedSizesToArray(unsigned char*) const in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::SolverState::SerializeWithCachedSizesToArray(unsigned char*) const in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::NetState::SerializeWithCachedSizesToArray(unsigned char*) const in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::NetStateRule::SerializeWithCachedSizesToArray(unsigned char*) const in caffe.pb.o
      ...
  "google::protobuf::internal::empty_string_", referenced from:
      caffe::Datum::SharedCtor() in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::Datum::MergeFrom(caffe::Datum const&) in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::Datum::~Datum() in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::Datum::SharedDtor() in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::Datum::Clear() in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::Datum::MergePartialFromCodedStream(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*) in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::NetParameter::SharedCtor() in caffe.pb.o
      ...
  "google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteBytesMaybeAliased(int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)", referenced from:
      caffe::Datum::SerializeWithCachedSizes(google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*) const in caffe.pb.o
  "google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteStringMaybeAliased(int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)", referenced from:
      caffe::FillerParameter::SerializeWithCachedSizes(google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*) const in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::NetParameter::SerializeWithCachedSizes(google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*) const in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::SolverParameter::SerializeWithCachedSizes(google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*) const in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::SolverState::SerializeWithCachedSizes(google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*) const in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::ParamSpec::SerializeWithCachedSizes(google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*) const in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::LayerParameter::SerializeWithCachedSizes(google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*) const in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::TransformationParameter::SerializeWithCachedSizes(google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*) const in caffe.pb.o
      ...
  "google::protobuf::internal::InitEmptyString()", referenced from:
      caffe::Datum::SharedCtor() in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::FillerParameter::SharedCtor() in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::NetParameter::SharedCtor() in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::SolverParameter::SharedCtor() in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::SolverState::SharedCtor() in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::NetState::SharedCtor() in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::NetStateRule::SharedCtor() in caffe.pb.o
      ...
  "google::protobuf::internal::empty_string_once_init_", referenced from:
      caffe::Datum::SharedCtor() in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::FillerParameter::SharedCtor() in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::NetParameter::SharedCtor() in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::SolverParameter::SharedCtor() in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::SolverState::SharedCtor() in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::NetState::SharedCtor() in caffe.pb.o
      caffe::NetStateRule::SharedCtor() in caffe.pb.o
      ...
  "google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::BytesUntilTotalBytesLimit() const", referenced from:
      bool google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::ReadPackedPrimitive<float, (google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::FieldType)2>(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*, google::protobuf::RepeatedField<float>*) in caffe.pb.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so] Error 1
```

Comment: What version of OSX? Did you make sure to follow the special libstdc++ instructions from http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_osx.html? I had this problem too when it was not linked properly. Don't use the pip install of protobuf, since it's not the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Did you build protobuf from source? I had a similar problem due to compiling protobuf and my project with differing versions of libc++.

I solved it by adding c++11 to CXXFLAGS.